# Should I use "forget" or "forgot" in the following case?

Tags: word-choice

> **Speaker A:** Hearing your father's records makes you forget about death because it makes you
>   feel as if he's still alive. As if death doesn't really
>   exist--wait, that doesn't make sense. Thinking about death not
>   existing is also thinking about death."
>
> **Speaker B:** Yeah, and you *forget/forgot* I
>   don't even remember when he was alive.

What's makes more sense in this case? *forget* or *forgot*?

Comment: 'are forgetting'. Though there is a problem with this example. The first 'your' etc seem generic (_When one hears one's father's records_ ...), but Speaker B is certainly referencing a definite person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***makes*** you feel as if he **'s** still alive

in the question
is present tense

A more reasonable answer seems to me:

[EDIT]

Speaker B: ***But*** you seem **to forget** **I don't even remember the time** when he was alive.

with the main also in present tense.

Comment: It is the second forget. Speaker A is talking in present time, but forgets that speaker B does not even remember.

Comment: OK, I adjusted the answer to that.